# Post values of check-boxes which are checked using AJAX in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<div class="of-tags">

    <label id="Physics"><input type="checkbox" id="venue[]"   onclick="changeclr('Physics');">Physics</label>

    <label id="chemestry"><input type="checkbox" id="venue[]" onclick="changeclr('chemestry');">chemestry</label>

    <label id="Maths" style="background: green;"><input type="checkbox" id="venue[]" onclick="changeclr('Maths');">Maths</label>

    <label id="General Knowledge" style="background: green;"><input type="checkbox" id="venue[]" onclick="changeclr('General Knowledge');">General Knowledge</label>

    <label id="Sience"><input type="checkbox" id="venue[]" onclick="changeclr('Sience');">Sience</label>

</div>
```

There is some code for example. I have five checkboxes and want to post these checkboxes values in separate variable or in an array or by separating them with comma to my next page, suppose insertvalues.php.

Comment: You have to add some code or Try adding a FIDDLE.

Comment: Use javascript [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) api. And pass it in the traditional XhttpRequest send method as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do this.one is collect each values separately or use `serialize()`. I would tell you to use `serialize()`

when you are calling ajax, do this,

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data : $('#form').serialize(),
    ...
});
```

You will receive all form elements in php url you have given. There you will get if the check box was checked or not. If checked, `$_POST` array will have check box name as index, else it will not be present in `$_POST` array.

If you want to check if its poster or not, use

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox name']){
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: i know very little about ajax so please can u explain more about serialize(). and one more doubt that i Have to post more fields not only checkboxes, i have more fields like name, address, age etc. so how will serialize post these fields on my next page.

Comment: `serialize()` will collect all input fields. So if u use `serialize()`  it ll add all fielas in the form

Comment: @NaveenSingh Check this link, you will get better idea. http://jsfiddle.net/zFhQB/275/. You can add any elements, it will get you in one array/ object.